# CloudFoundry Error 503 Unexpected Response from service gateway

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have been using CloudFoundry for 4 months now, deploying my application through either Wavemaker or VMC.  Today when I tried to update my application, I started receiving the following error:

Error 502 Bad Gateway Bad Gateway

when I try to use VMC to tunnel to my service to check on the status of the database I receive

CFoundry::ServiceGatewayError: 503: Unexpected response from service gateway

I could just delete the Postgres service and create a new one, but then I would lose my data.  I do have a backup, but there have been many updates to the copy on CloudFoundry copy, and therefore I am loath to delete it.  I have been trying to make changes to the application to allow me to easily copy data straight out of the web page, as there is no good solution for database backups / dumps from CloudFoundry.

So I am stuck - is it possible to force the service to restart?

Answer (score 0):

When this occurs it's often due to problems with Caldecott, just remove it and then retry tunnelling to the service;

vmc delete caldecott

vmc tunnel my_mysql_service

Comment: Would be lovely if it wasn't always a "Error 503: Unexpected response from service gateway" response.